Does Acts quote a mistranslation of the Hebrew bible in support of a doctrine?
Acts 15 quotes Amos 9 in order to settle a debate about preaching the Christian gospel to non-Jews:

I will rebuild the dwelling of David, which has fallen;
from its ruins I will rebuild it, and I will set it up, so that all other peoples may seek the Lord— even all the Gentiles over whom my name has been called. Acts 15:16-17

This quote comes from the Septuagint Amos, with a few relevant changes. “The Lord” is an addition of Acts.
The Greek and the Hebrew readings of this quoted passage have an interesting relationship. The important section in Amos 9:12 reads:

לְמַעַן יִירְשׁוּ אֶת־שְׁאֵרִית אֱדוֹם
...that they may possess the remnant of Edom...

This section is rendered in the LXX Amos 9:11 (and in Acts with the aforementioned change) as:

ὅπως ἐκζητήσωσιν οἱ κατάλοιποι τῶν ἀνθρώπων
...so that the remnant of the people might seek.

The cause of this mistranslation appears the be that a Greek speaking translator confused אדום (Edom) with אדם (Adam) meaning "man" or "mankind", probably because of a lack of a mater lectionis. The verb יירשׁו meaning "to possess", was also mistaken as the similar appearing verb ידרשׁו meaning "to seek".
The Hebrew appears to be the better reading than the LXX for two reasons:

An obvious garbling of the verse with a lack of a direct object for εκζητησωσιν ("that they may seek")
The context makes more sense in the Hebrew. The idea that David's restored house reasserting authority will possess the remnant of Edom fits in context. A restored house of David causing nations to seek the Lord does not fit the rest of Amos.

Did the LXX make translation mistakes in this passage? Is that mistake in turn propagated forward by the author of Acts to support early church doctrine?

In fairness, the witnesses we have for the LXX are earlier than those we have for the MT, so there has been a lot of debate around what to do when the two diverge - are they LXX mistranslations (by the 72 Hebrew-speaking elders who compiled it...), or do they reflect later modifications of the MT to combat Christian readings of the text? The NT typically follows the LXX even where it diverges from the MT and (to my awareness) never seems to scrutinise its readings, whether for doctrinal reasons or otherwise.

I don't see the relevance of your first point, the translation of the "72 Hebrew-speaking elders" that you referenced was of only the Pentateuch - not Sefer Amos (which is what this question is about)

Apologies, you're correct, I was unaware of that nuance - though regardless of authorship the point about it ultimately being an earlier witness still stands - we can assume the MT preserves an earlier tradition, but it's still an assumption. Some have taken the fact that NT authors never seem to question these divergences may suggest there were no substantial divergences at the time when they quoted them.

@Stevecanhelp your opinions would be welcome in an answer :) I'll say that I offered (what I think are) compelling explanations for why the extant Greek translation is 1. missing an object and 2. dropped the mention of Edom in favor of ἀνθρώπων. Hence why I think the translator likely had a proto-MT Sefer Amos in view when translating this passage and made the mistakes I mentioned

Edom or Adam is a minor point in this passage for church doctrine.  The main point is the uncontested וְכָל־הַגֹּויִ֔ם (and all the nations/Gentiles).

גּוֹי m. (b. h.; cmp. גֵּו) crowd, people, nation; pl. גּוֹיִם gentiles, fr. which גּוֹי = נָכְרִי or עכו״ם, gentile, idolator. Tosef. Ab. Zar. III, 4 sq.; Y. ib. IV, 41a top contrad. to כותי (Bab. ib. 29a נכרי); a. v. fr.—Pl. גּוֹיִים, גּוֹיִם.
Jastrow, M. (1903). In A Dictionary of the Targumim, the Talmud Babli and Yerushalmi, and the Midrashic Literature and II (Vol. 1, p. 220). Luzac & Co.; G. P. Putnam’s Sons.

@PerryWebb I'm unclear on what you mean by "The main point is the uncontested וְכָל־הַגֹּויִ֔ם". The disputed passage regarding the reconquest of Edom is what the question is about, because the author of Acts appears to completely breeze past the original context and (what I argue is) the original Hebrew

My point is the mistranslation issue does not impact the church doctrine. I didn't put that in answer because it is not really addressing the question as far as interpretating this passage.

You are asking two questions:

Did the LXX make translation mistakes in this passage?
Is that mistake in turn propagated forward by the author of Acts to support early church doctrine?

Let's tackle them.
Did the LXX make translation mistakes in this passage?
The Hebrew reads:

”לְמַ֨עַן יִֽירְשׁ֜וּ אֶת־שְׁאֵרִ֤ית אֱדוֹם֙ וְכָל־הַגּוֹיִ֔ם אֲשֶׁר־נִקְרָ֥א שְׁמִ֖י עֲלֵיהֶ֑ם נְאֻם־יְהוָ֖ה עֹ֥שֶׂה זֹּֽאת׃“ (עמוס ט׃יב BHQ-12)

Likewise, the Greek:

“ὅπως ἐκζητήσωσιν οἱ κατάλοιποι τῶν ἀνθρώπων, καὶ πάντα τὰ ἔθνη ἐφ’ οὓς ἐπικέκληται τὸ ὄνομά μου ἐπ’ αὐτούς, λέγει Κύριος ὁ ποιῶν ταῦτα.” (Amos 9:12 LXXS-T)

As to the variant, יִֽירְשׁ֜וּ vs. ἐκζητήσωσιν, the BHQ gives this commentary:

9:12  יִֽירְשׁ֜וּ G presupposes a Vorlage יִדְרְשׁוּ. The citation in
Acts 15:17 agrees with G. This variant has to be considered in
conjunction with the following phrase, on which see the comment.
אֶת־שְׁאֵרִ֤ית אֱדוֹם֙ G may presuppose a Vorlage without ‏את‎ or the
vocalic ‏ו‎ in the last word, which is then vocalized as ‏אָדָם. The
phrase was then understood as the subj. rather than the obj. of the
preceding verb. GMss supply an object. The citation in Acts 15:17
agrees with GMss. These variants have to be considered in conjunction
with the preceding verb. For a defence of the originality of G’s
presumed Vorlage, see Jones, Formation, 183–91. Another possibility is
that G misread ‏י‎ as ‏ד‎ in the verb, and omitted ‏את in an attempt
to make sense of the passage, and that its Vorlage differed from M
only in the defective writing of אדום. See Gelston, “Some Hebrew
Misreadings,” 498–99.
(Anthony Gelston, eds. Biblia Hebraica Quinta, Fascicle 13: The Twelve
Minor Prophets. Accordance electronic ed. (Stuttgart: Deutsche
Bibelgesellschaft, 2010), paragraph 1018.)

It seems, then that the Greek translators of Amos mistook יָרַשׁ for דָּרַשׁ. This is not the first example of weaknesses in the Greek translations of the 12. Much of the minor prophets were translated hundreds of years after the LXX. And, there is evidence that they weren't always careful in their translations. This would be one example.
This leads us to the second question:
Is that mistake in turn propagated forward by the author of Acts to support early church doctrine?
In order for this question to be true (that James is using a defective translation), one has to prove that James is quoting, verbatim, the OT authors from the Greek translation, as if the Greek were somehow superior to the Hebrew.
The problem with this train of thought is that, first, you have to prove that James is quoting the Greek translation.  Sure, here it might seem as if he's quoting the Greek translation. But what do we do with the substantive differences between the James (as Luke records it) and the Greek version of Amos?  For here are the words as they are handed down to us:

“<11> Εν τῇ ἡμέρᾳ ἐκείνῃ ἀναστήσω τὴν σκηνὴν Δαυεὶδ τὴν πεπτωκυῖαν, καὶ ἀνοικοδομήσω τὰ πεπτωκότα αὐτῆς, καὶ τὰ κατεσκαμμένα αὐτῆς ἀναστήσω, καὶ ἀνοικοδομήσω αὐτὴν καθὼς αἱ ἡμέραι τοῦ αἰῶνος, <12> ὅπως ἐκζητήσωσιν οἱ κατάλοιποι τῶν ἀνθρώπων, καὶ πάντα τὰ ἔθνη ἐφ’ οὓς ἐπικέκληται τὸ ὄνομά μου ἐπ’ αὐτούς, λέγει Κύριος ὁ ποιῶν ταῦτα.” (Amos 9:11-12 LXXS-T)
“«16» μετὰ ταῦτα ἀναστρέψω καὶ ἀνοικοδομήσω τὴν σκηνὴν Δαυεὶδ τὴν πεπτωκυῖαν καὶ τὰ κατεσκαμμένα αὐτῆς ἀνοικοδομήσω καὶ ἀνορθώσω αὐτήν· «17» ὅπως ἂν ἐκζητήσωσιν οἱ κατάλοιποι τῶν ἀνθρώπων τὸν κύριον καὶ πάντα τὰ ἔθνη, ἐφ’ οὓς ἐπικέκληται τὸ ὄνομά μου ἐπ’ αὐτούς, λέγει κύριος ὁ ποιῶν ταῦτα” (Πράξεις 15·16-17 THGNT-T)

It doesn't take a whole lot of time to see that there are some substantive differences between what James says (linguistically) and what the Greek version says. The Greek version says, "ἀναστήσω" and yet James says, "ἀναστρέψω." The Greek version says, "Εν τῇ ἡμέρᾳ ἐκείνῃ" (on that day), but James says, "μετὰ ταῦτα" (after these [days]).  And, it wouldn't be different to make a long list of the differences.
Solution
Why would James choose some words that fit nicely within the Greek version, and then, make sizable exeptions even to the Masoretic text?  The answer is found in the old proverb: The biblical authors do not quote verses. Instead, they quote contexts.  In other words, they do not quote verses, they, instead, quote larger thought-units, even what we would call chapters today.
A further example
At the end of 1 cor. 15, we have a similar example:

“ποῦ σου, θάνατε, τὸ νῖκος; ποῦ σου, θάνατε, τὸ κέντρον;” (Κορινθίους α 15·55 THGNT-T)

The problem, though, is this is not what Isaiah says (in the LXX, strictly speaking).  What Isaiah says is:

”בִּלַּ֤ע הַמָּ֙וֶת֙ לָנֶ֔צַח וּמָחָ֨ה אֲדֹנָ֧י יְהוִ֛ה דִּמְעָ֖ה מֵעַ֣ל כָּל־פָּנִ֑ים וְחֶרְפַּ֣ת עַמּ֗וֹ יָסִיר֙ מֵעַ֣ל כָּל־הָאָ֔רֶץ כִּ֥י יְהוָ֖ה דִּבֵּֽר׃“ (ישׁעיה כה׃ח HMT-W4)

In my own notes for the opening word of the verse, בִּלַּ֤ע, I have this paragraph:

The note here in the apparatus notes that in a few Medieval
manuscripts the copulative is added.  And in the Syriac it’s rendered
as an Ithpeel (ܘܢܬܒܠܥ݂), which the editor concludes that the text
could be repointed as a Pual in Hebrew.  The result of the change
would mean very little.  Instead of “He” swallowing death, death
“would be swallowed.”  The editor makes note of it (evidently) because
Paul, in 1 Cor. 15:54, (supposedly) goes with the text revised by
Theodotian (Θ´ κατεποθη ο θ. εις νικος) instead of the standard LXX
text (“κατέπιεν ὁ θάνατος ἰσχύσας” (Is. 25:8 LXXS-T))  The LXX
here, in the standard text is nonsensical, making death the subject
instead of “he.” It is possible that Paul is quoting בלע as a Pual
(like the Syriac,  ܘܢܬܒܠܥ݂).  But it’s more likely that he’s quoting
the MT more loosely to fit his audience.  He’s definitely not quoting
the LXX here.  However, it may be the case that he’s quoting the
Aramaic/Syriac, since he both uses a passive (ܘܢܬܒܠܥ݂), and he
translates נֵצַח as ⲛⲓⲕⲟⲥ.

The LXX here is incomprehensible in this verse.  And yet, it is common place to hear NT commentators say that Paul is quoting the LXX here. So why would Paul quote a defective part of the OT?  Is it that he has an inferior copy of the text that he is working with? A far better explanation is that the old proverb is true: Paul is not quoting a verse. Instead, he is quoting a context.  He freely cites the full context of that chapter in Isaiah (or even the entire prophetic corpus of Isaiah).
So, to take us back to Acts, James (through Luke) can quote the Greek version (since that what the Jews were used to). But that does not mean that is is only doing that.  He is freely quoting the entire context of Amos 9 (or more) as flexibly as he sees fit.  In the greater context "seeking out" fits just fine. This would also account for the times that James sticks more closely with the Masoretic text instead of the Greek version here.
So, Divine Inspiration/Preservation is not at stake when one repeatedly sees this pattern: The biblical authors (esp. in the NT) quote a context, not a verse. But, yes, Divine Inspiration/Preservation would definitely be called into question if one holds to the view that the LXX is somehow exclusively cited by the NT authors or if one holds that the LXX (or here the Greek translation later than the LXX) is at a higher level than the Masoretic text.

This is an extremely well written answer. You make a point that Acts is quoting the context of Amos when rendering Amos 9, not the LXX (using the term LXX colloquially). It seems like a remarkable coincidence that the Lukan citation would repeat the exact mistake the LXX translator did WRT ἐκζητήσωσιν while simultaneously not citing it. I also don't quite follow how Amos 9 works with your idea of "citing contexts", Daniel McClellan states "...Amos 9, which refer only to the military reconquest of lands belonging to YHWH at Israel’s political height"

If we want an expansion on what ἐκζητήσωσιν looks like, all we have to do is look at the next few verses.  The Lord restores (vs. 11) = cause. Effect: they  overtake (13, וְנִגַּ֤שׁ), rebuild (14, rebuild), plant (14, וְנָטְע֣וּ), etc. That looks a whole-lot like seeking out the Lord and following the Lord's will.  The word 'seeking' isn't there. instead, the action is. Again, the NT writers cite a context, not a verse.

The obvious issue with your interpretation is the identity of 'they', the subject of those verbs. 'They' with regards to the verbs following the restoration of the house of David ( יִירְשׁוּ, נִגַּשׁ, בָנוּ) is unambiguously the house of David or Israel

Augustine has handed down to us the proverb: novum testamentum in vetere latet; vetus testamentum in novo patet.. (The new testament is hidden in the old, the old testament is revealed in the new testament).  While it could be said that the first, primary referent in the Amos context is Israel, James lets us know that the fulfillment is found in the Acts context in the Gentiles being enfolded into the formerly fallen tent of David.  cf. Acts 15:16-18. I don't see any issue with that at all. However, the other point of view has many difficulties.

However, the other point of view has many difficulties - what do you mean by that?

Word plays in the text of the Bible are the most neglected and the least known aspect of the biblical interpretation. And they are everywhere.
One of the most obvious ones is David portrayed as the new Adam in the 1 Book of Samuel. While hiding from Saul he lived at some point in En Gedi (עֵין גֶּדִי), that is not only a play on words of the garden of Eden (gan eden גַּן־עֵדֶן) but also looked like a little paradise.
Edom is also used as a word play of Adam (the first human but mainly the humanity). It is quite obvious considering so many similarities between those two characters. Their names are inspired by the colour red. Edom because of the reddens of his body hair when he was born, and Adam because he was made out of the reddish soil. They both sold they birthright to crafty characters for food. To name the clearest ones.
Now, what if the ancient rabbis that translated the older form of the Hebrew OT that the MT knew a lot more about those word plays then the ignorant us? Is it possible that this knowledge would affect the translations of certain passages that have different meaning in Greek than in Hebrew?
Also, let us not forget the influence of the Holly Spirit not only on the authors of the biblical books but also on the translators.
The motives of the skull crasher and the conqueror of the enemy gates are only two out of many in the Bible. Obviously, they are both messianic. Jesus Christ was the one that crushed the head of the serpent and kicked open the gates of hades. Both of those motives and Edom appear in verses of Numbers 24:

17 “I see him, but not now; I behold him, but not near. A star will
come out of Jacob; a scepter will rise out of Israel. He will crush
the foreheads of Moab, the skulls of all the people of Sheth.  18 Edom
will be conquered; Seir, his enemy, will be conquered, but Israel will
grow strong.

Verse 18 is a hyperlink and a word play of Genesis 24:60:

And they blessed Rebekah, and said unto her: 'Our sister, be thou the
mother of thousands of ten thousands, and let thy seed conquer the
gate of those that hate them.'

Where Seir (שֵׂעִיר) and the gate (shaar שַׁעַר) sound very similar.
Let's remember that the ancient Israel and the surrounding nations served as a microcosm representing the whole world. Additionally, the two siblings, Jacob/Israel and Esau, symbolise two groups of peoples. The chosen of God, that are transformed by the Spirit of God and serve as intermediary royal priesthood. And the unrepented/ignorant rest.
The OT prophesied that the Messiah will be the Lord of all. As in Psalm 60:

Gilead is mine, and Manasseh is mine; Ephraim is my helmet, Judah is
my scepter.  Moab is my washbasin, on Edom I toss my sandal; over
Philistia I shout in triumph.”

The the throwing of the sandal is obviously an euphemism for the custom of the levirate marriage (Ruth 4:7)
Sumarising, the section of Amos 9 quoted in Acts 15 is not a mistranslation. It is a legitimate interpretation, based on conciled to the previous generation truths contained in the scriptures of the OT.
I strongly recommend the book by Scott B. Noegel, “Wordplay” in Ancient Near Eastern Texts.

I have more than a few follow up questions after reading this, but one that stood out to me was this curious claim: “The OT prophesied that the Messiah will be the Lord of all. As in Psalm 60”. Moab is called a washbasin, a shoe is thrown at Edom, and Philistia is defeated - there is literally not one positive thing said here about Israel’s enemies. This is a triumphal psalm and the verse you quote is boasting of how humiliated each of the named nations is, shoe being thrown included. A careful reader may notice how in Ruth 4:7 the shoe isn’t tossed at the bride to be?

God, through Isaiah, said, “For my thoughts are not your thoughts, neither are your ways my ways”. What is good and honorable in our eyes is not in His. So our understanding is in direct opposition to God's character. His greatest victory was being rejected, spat on, bitten, flogged and nailed to a rugged cross.

Your literal interpretation of the psalm is wrong.

For consistency, when the Amalekites were destroyed and G-d said that he would be at war with them forever, they were actually being honored?

Amalek (the people who separate from the head) is a completely different rabbit hole. I don't quite understand that motive or its full meaning.

In revelation 3:7-9 John puts Isaiah 43:1-7, 45:14-17 on their heads and calls the gentile believers Israel and the Judean unbelievers enemies of God. Nothing is as it seems at first glance.

You're just claiming that my example is different without explaining how. You also make a claim that "our understanding is in direct opposition to God's character", which makes me unclear on how you would perform exegesis in the first place
